# ASA Site to Site VPN Version 8.4 Natting Same Subnets

Tags: cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

My site and client site has same Lan IP range.
Both using ASA version 8.4

Site A : 192.168.18.0
Site B : 192.168.18.0

Please tell me how to do Natting on 8.4

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Kinnu

Comment: How do you want the communication to look - since they're overlapping IP ranges, should they translate such that when site A gets communication from site B, it sees the traffic from site B's `192.168.18.100` as being from, say, `192.168.20.100`?

Comment: Hi shane, I tried put in simple words below

I have a site to site On ASA. 
MY network is 192.168.18.0/24 
Clinet A : network is 192.168.0.1/24 
Now recently one new client B is adding, Now i need to create a site to site VPN for client B as well. 
Client B: network is 192.168.0.1/24 
Now both client A and Client B has same Lan network. Can you give tell me how to config. 
Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Ok, got it.  Are you able to make configuration changes on the ASAs at the client's side?